# How to send SMS(arabic,parsi) from C# via SerialPort

Tags: c#

this may code but is not support language (arabic,persian,...). SMS=????????????

```
`SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
        sp.PortName = "COM19";
        sp.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        sp.Open();
        sp.Write("AT\r");
        sp.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
        sp.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"\r\n");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
        sp.Write(textBox2.Text + "\x1A");
        MessageBox.Show("Send SMS successfulled");
        sp.Close();`
```

Comment: Not if you don't change the SerialPort.Encoding property.  The default is ASCIIEncoding, that's going to be a lot of question marks.  What you are supposed to change it to is a guess, best to ask your service provider.  But you'd start guessing at Encoding.Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You could consume some online translator apis and translate your test to your desired language and then send that through sms.

Example, below link gives you an idea of how to translate your text from English to Arabic or any other language using c# and google api.

[Google Translate API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shahpiyush/2007/06/09/translate-your-text-using-google-apis/)

[Example Link](http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text=Text&langpair=en%7Car)